# rare occuring nullpointer exception (game programming Java)

Tags: java

I am building this game in Java. Basically it is minecraft in 2D. I made it so that block objects are deleted when pressed. My block object rendering sometimes gives a nullpointerexception after clicking/deleting a block (randomly after about 200 blocks). It seems as if the object is sometimes deleted while the game is in the renderingloop. When I add a try-catch, the next render cycle does not have the error anymore. Any ideas what is causing this? Is this gameloop a solid one, I suspect that is what is causing my error.

Render method in my handler:

```
LinkedList<GameObject> object = new LinkedList<GameObject>();

public void render(Graphics g){
    for(int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++){
        GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);//sometimes nullpointer when getting the object I clicked on
        tempObject.render(g);
    }
}
```

Deleting with mouseInput

```
for(int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++){
        if(handler.object.get(i).getID() == ID.Block){
            int x1 = (int) handler.object.get(i).getX();
            int y1 = (int) handler.object.get(i).getY();
            //if mouse is over object
            if((MouseX >= x1+1 && MouseX <= (x1 +32-1)) && (MouseY >= y1+1 && MouseY <= (y1 +32-1))){
                Block b = (Block) handler.object.get(i);
                inventory.addInventoryBlocks(b.getType(), 1);
                handler.removeObject(handler.object.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
```

Gameloop:

```
public void run() {
    this.requestFocus();
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double amountOfTicks = 60;
    double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
    double delta = 0;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int frames = 0;
    while(running){
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;
            while(delta >= 1){
                tick();
                delta--;
            }
        if(running)
            render();
        frames++;

        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000){
            timer += 1000;
            //System.out.println("FPS: " + frames);
            frames = 0;
        }
    }
    stop();
}
```

Comment: What is the thread structure? Where does the game loop run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your mouse input handler runs as a seperate thread. In this case the deletion of a block can occure within your rendering loop.

A solution would be not to delete the blocks immediately in your mouse handler but to save the blocks to delete in a separate array. These blocks can be handled at a dedicated position in your main loop right before rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your mouse handler is running in the AWT thread while the render is running in another thread. In this case you would be suffering of concurrency troubles.

Try using a critical section.

```
public static Object lock = new Object();

public void render(Graphics g){
    synchronized(lock)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++){
            GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);//sometimes nullpointer when getting the object I clicked on
           tempObject.render(g);
        }
    }
}

void mouseInputHandler()
{
    synchronized( lock )
    {
        code
    }
}
```

This could be better refined knowing more about your code's structure but it should get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using different threads for updating the game state and rendering, this behavior does not seem that odd to me, as one thread might have deleted an object as the other tries to render it.

A good way to debug this is to force *sequential* execution of your code. Check if the current behavior persists. A nice introduction (Android) to game loops can be found [here](http://obviam.net/index.php/a-very-basic-the-game-loop-for-android/)